# Given a dictionary, how to replace an item in the list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a dictionary such as:

```
sample_dict = {'test':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
```

how do I change an item in the list with something else.

example:

```
def replace_item(sample_dict, item, new_item):
      pass

>>> replace_item({'test':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}, 'd', 'f')
>>> {'test':['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'e']}
```

Comment: If the dictionary has multiple key/value pairs, should the replacement apply to every value or just a certain one?

Comment: Assuming that it will only have one key/value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample_dict = {'test': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}

def replace_item(sample_dict, item, new_item):
    list = sample_dict['test']
    list[list.index(item)] = new_item

replace_item(sample_dict, 'd', 'f')
# {'test': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'e']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply retrieve the list and modify it, since the dictionary only stores a reference to the list, not the list itself.